# Trouble in solving a question related to differentiation.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**The question is** :

> Let $g : \mathbb {R} \longrightarrow \mathbb {R}$ be a differentiable function such that $|g'(x)| \leq M$ for all $x \in \mathbb {R}$. For what values of $k$ will the function $f(x) = x + kg(x)$ be necessarily one-to-one?

Is there any possible value of $k$ other than $0$? Please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: If a differentiable function has non-zero derivative, then it is 1-1.

Comment: Then @Marlin according to you $|k| < \frac {1} {M}$.Isn't it?But how can I prove the result what you have stated?Please help me.

Comment: If the derivative is non-zero everywhere, it's always positive and hence (strictly) increasing or similarly always negative and (strictly) decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

The above comments by Merlin and daruma are both correct. In what follows I aim to fill in all of the details so the result is 100% clear.

In order to prove that the derivative being strictly positive guarantees that the function is strictly increasing, we can use the mean value theorem. What follows mirrors Theorems 5.9-5.11 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* with some modifications.

Let $f$ be a differentiable real function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and let $x_2 > x_1$. Put $$h(t) = [f(x_2) - f(x_1)]t - (x_2 - x_1)\cdot f(t)$$ Then $h$ is continuous on $[x_1,x_2]$ and differentiable on $(x_1,x_2)$. Moreover, $$h(x_1) = f(x_2)x_1 - f(x_1)x_2 = h(x_2)$$ If we show that $h'(x)=0$ for some $x \in (x_1, x_2)$ then it will follow that for this $x$: $$f(x_2)-f(x_1) = (x_2 - x_1) \cdot f'(x) $$ If $h$ is constant, then this holds automatically for any $x \in (x_1, x_2)$.

Thus, assume without loss of generality that $h$ is not constant. Because $h(t)$ is continuous, it attains both its minimum and maximum on $[x_1, x_2]$ (possibly at the endpoints). Because we are assuming that $h(t)$ is not constant on $[x_1, x_2]$, it follows that for some $t \in (x_1,x_2)$, we have either $h(t) > h(a)$ or $h(t) < h(a)$ (because if $h(t)=h(a)$ for all $ t \in (x_1, x_2)$, $h$ would be constant).

If $h(t) > h(a)$, then let $x$ be the point in $(x_1, x_2)$ where $h$ attains its maximum, and if $h(t) < h(a)$, let $x$ be the point in $(x_1, x_2)$ where $h$ attains its minimum. Because $h(x_1)=h(x_2)$ and $h$ is not constant, we know that in the former case that the maximum cannot occur at the endpoints of the interval, and in the latter case that the minimum cannot occur at the endpoints of the interval.

That $h'(x)=0$ in either case follows from this lemma (Theorem 5.8 in Rudin): *If $h$ is defined on  $[x_1,x_2]$ and $h$ has a local maximum or minimum at $x \in (x_1, x_2)$ and $h'(x)$ exists, then $h'(x)=0$.*

**Proof:** (of lemma) Assume $x$ is a local minimum. Choose $\delta$ such that for all $y \in (x-\delta, x+\delta) \cap [x_1,x_2]$, we have $h(x) < h(y)$. Then for all $t \in (x-\delta, x) \cap [x_1,x_2]$ we have $$\frac{h(t) - h(x)}{t-x} \le 0$$ Letting $ t \to x^-$, we get $h'(x) \le 0$. Likewise, for all $t \in (x, x+\delta) \cap [x_1, x_2]$, we have $$\frac{h(t)-h(x)}{t-x}\ge 0$$ and thus letting $t \to x^+$, we get $h'(x) \ge 0$. Therefore $h'(x)=0$.

The case for $x$ a local maximum is entirely similar; or alternatively one can just use the above proof for $-h(x)$, in which case $x$ is a local minimum. $\blacksquare$

Thus we have shown that in $(x_1, x_2)$, there must exist an $x \in (x_1, x_2)$ such that $$f(x_2) - f(x_1) = (x_2 - x_1)\cdot f'(x) $$ By the assumption that $x_2 > x_1 \implies (x_2 - x_1) >0$ and that $f'(x)$ was strictly positive, i.e. $f'(x) > 0$, it follows that $f(x_2) - f(x_1) > 0  \implies f(x_2) > f(x_1)$. Thus we have shown that, for all $x_1, x_2$ such that $x_1 < x_2$, we have $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$.

Likewise, if $f'(x) <0$, i.e. is strictly negative, then it follows immediately that $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$ for $x_1 < x_2$. (The proof is exactly analogous, or substitute $-f(x)$ into the above, since $-f'(x) >0$.)

How does the function being strictly increasing or decreasing ensure that it is $1-1$? First we show that $f$ must be surjective. Since $f$ is continuous (since it is differentiable) and defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$, by a corollary the intermediate value theorem (use the exhaustion of the real line by compact intervals), the only way that its range would not be all of $\mathbb{R}$ is if it were bounded above or below. However, this is impossible since $f$ is defined on *all* of $\mathbb{R}$ (which is unbounded) and is strictly increasing/decreasing. Now we show that $f$ must be injective. Let $x_1, x_2$ be such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Since $x_1 \not= x_2$ we have either $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$ or $f(x_2) < f(x_1)$ due to the fact that $f$ is strictly increasing/decreasing; since neither of these two holds, we must have $x_1 = x_2$ and thus it follows that $f$ is injective. Being both injective and surjective, it follows that $f$ is 1-1.

So a sufficient condition to ensure that $f(x)=x+kg(x)$ is 1-1 is that either $f'(x)$ remains strictly positive or that $f'(x)$ remains strictly negative.

In the first case, we want to have $f'(x) = 1 +kg'(x) >0$. As you correctly noted, $k=0$ works for this, so we can divide this into two sub-cases: $k >0$ and $k<0$. In the first sub-case, we have $1+kM >1 + kg'(x) > 1 +k(-M) > 0$. The first inequality is redundant, so it reduces to $1 + kg'(x) > 1-kM > 0$. This implies that $0< k < \frac{1}{M}$. Now for the second sub-case, $k < 0$, then we have $1 + k(-M) > 1+kg'(x) > 1 +kM > 0$. As before, the first inequality is redundant, and thus the condition reduces to $1 + kg'(x) > 1 + kM > 0$ which implies $kM > -1 $ and thus that $0>k>\frac{1}{M}$.

Thus, as you noted in the comments, for $f'(x)>0$, we have $|k|<\frac{1}{M}$.

Now for the case $f'(x) = 1 + kg'(x) <0$. Unlike last time, $k=0$ clearly does not work. Let us consider $k>0$ briefly; if this held for any such $k$, we would have: $1+k(-M) < 1 +kg'(x) < 1+kM < 0$. However, since $M>0$, there is no $k>0$ such that this holds. Therefore, we now consider the sub-case of $k<0$; we get $1+kM < 1 + kg'(x) < 1 +k(-M) <0$. However, this again is impossible, since $k(-M)>0$.

Therefore, the correct answer, as you said, is $|k|<\frac{1}{M}$.